# Selenium IDE - Confirmation Issues

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a link on my page that I need to click in order to delete a profile. When I click it, a confirmation dialog pops up asking to confirm it (that one which sets the background dark and a dialog appears, not an actual window pop-up). So, if I insert a command `assertConformation`, it gives me an error saying that it does not exist. If I don't use this command, selenium gives error saying that there was a confirmation ... weird right? Here are the evidences:

**WITHOUT THE COMMAND:**

[image]

**WITH THE COMMAND:**

[image]

Do you guys know what can I do in this case? This is the type of confirmation:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `waitForConfirmation` or `waitForConfirmationPresent` ?

Comment: yes, same thing -- http://imgur.com/PsNITc2 -- it waits for any confirmation, it passes successfully, and then get error

Comment: I suggest you to prevent confirmation using javascript. That's not a clear way but it will save a lot of your time.

Comment: Have you tried including the "\\" in your variables? The output would be like this one **${path}${tc}Step3.JPG**

Comment: @RodelBernal Yes I also did the too :)

Comment: @Antesser is this possible to do using any Selenium command? I don't have access to the page code to modify it

Comment: You can cast any javascript command with Selenium IDE. That means that you can change everything on the page. If your case is simple it is possible to set onclick='' for your link. If your case is hard maybe you need to recreate a function. If your case is very hard you can even create your own delete_user button. Please provide the HTML code of the link and the script part of the webpage and I will try to provide a Selenium IDE command to kill the confirmation. But it's still a workaround.

Comment: The question is more suitable for http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ - Software Quality Assurance & Testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about consuming the confirmation. If the confirmation is generated, you have to use `waitForConfirmation` and `storeConfirmation`, otherwise the test-case will fail.

Read the Selenium IDE function help (in **bold**):

> **storeConfirmation(variableName)** Generated from getConfirmation()
>
> Returns:
>   the message of the most recent JavaScript confirmation dialog
>
> Retrieves the message of a JavaScript confirmation dialog generated during the previous action.
>
> By default, the confirm function will return true, having the same effect as manually clicking OK. This can be changed by prior execution
>   of the chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation command.
>
> **If an confirmation is generated but you do not consume it with getConfirmation, the next Selenium action will fail.**
>
> NOTE: under Selenium, JavaScript confirmations will NOT pop up a visible dialog.
>
> NOTE: Selenium does NOT support JavaScript confirmations that are generated in a page's onload() event handler. In this case a visible
>   dialog WILL be generated and Selenium will hang until you manually
>   click OK.

If the confirmation is generated only sometimes, I recocomend to use **Selblocks** and the `storeConfirmationPresent` and `if` commands.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at the **chooseOkOnNextConfirmation** command?

> Undo the effect of calling chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation. Note that Selenium's overridden window.confirm() function will normally
>   automatically return true, as if the user had manually clicked OK, so
>   you shouldn't need to use this command unless for some reason you need
>   to change your mind prior to the next confirmation. After any
>   confirmation, Selenium will resume using the default behavior for
>   future confirmations, automatically returning true (OK) unless/until
>   you explicitly call chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation for each
>   confirmation.
>
> Take note - every time a confirmation comes up, you must consume it with a corresponding getConfirmation, or else the next selenium
>   operation will fail.

that will get you past the alert box, if you want to ensure a confirmation box pops up, I suggest **waitForConfirmation** or **waitForAlert**